# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am developing Spring MVC + POI + Hibernate example by taking a reference from link : https://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/02/spring-3-apache-poi-hibernate-creating.html?showComment=1471543913666#c3056350689763201958. In this project I used the latest dependencies of Spring Framework version `4.3.1.RELEASE`.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'downloadController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'downloadService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'downloadService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

It looks to be there is some version mismatched between the dependencies but not sure which.

The updated **pom.xml** for reference:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <commons-digester.version>2.1</commons-digester.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>
        <poi.version>3.6</poi.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Web and Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Digester -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-digester.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Collection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.ga</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet API, JSTL, Standard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The other code is kept as it is.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError = inconsistent libs used. i.e Some dependency was compiled with some other dependency requirement, yet at runtime you aren't using that combination. So Spring + Hibernate are inconsistent, consequently you look at the Maven pom.xml for those projects and see what they need. Why use latest Spring if not upgrading HIbernate??!!!

Comment: Actually I was looking upgrade both spring and Hibernate and others too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lots of modification needs to be done in order to use the latest dependencies. I used Spring version `4.3.1.RELEASE` and Hibernate version `4.3.11.Final` and also used latest version of dependencies for others too.

Here you need to change below in `hibernate-context.xml`

**For hibernate 3.0**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="org.krams.tutorial"/>
```

**For Hibernate 4.0.x**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="org.krams.tutorial"/>
```

Also:
**For hibernate 3.0**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

**For Hibernate 4.0**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

IMP Note:
**Hibernate 3.5 and onward contains Hibernate Annotations.** : You should remove the dependency on `hibernate-annotations`.

The latest pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <commons-digester.version>2.1</commons-digester.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>
        <poi.version>3.6</poi.version>
        <javassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javassist.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <persistence-api-version>1.0.2</persistence-api-version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Web and Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Digester -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-digester.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Collection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLib Nodep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.3.2.GA</version> -->
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistent API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${persistence-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet API, JSTL, Standard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```